# Want to change the value of a data member in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a javascript prototype like this.

```
Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels = function(element, opts)
{
    this.element = this.getElement(element);
    this.defaultTab = 0; // Show the first panel by default.
    this.tabSelectedClass = "TabbedPanelsTabSelected";
    this.tabHoverClass = "TabbedPanelsTabHover";
    this.tabFocusedClass = "TabbedPanelsTabFocused";
    this.panelVisibleClass = "TabbedPanelsContentVisible";
    this.focusElement = null;
    this.hasFocus = false;
    this.currentTabIndex = 0;
    this.enableKeyboardNavigation = true;
    this.nextPanelKeyCode = Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_RIGHT;
    this.previousPanelKeyCode = Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_LEFT;

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.setOptions(this, opts);

    // If the defaultTab is expressed as a number/index, convert
    // it to an element.

    if (typeof (this.defaultTab) == "number")
    {
        if (this.defaultTab < 0)
            this.defaultTab = 0;
        else
        {
            var count = this.getTabbedPanelCount();
            if (this.defaultTab >= count)
                this.defaultTab = (count > 1) ? (count - 1) : 0;
        }

        this.defaultTab = this.getTabs()[this.defaultTab];
    }

    // The defaultTab property is supposed to be the tab element for the tab content
    // to show by default. The caller is allowed to pass in the element itself or the
    // element's id, so we need to convert the current value to an element if necessary.

    if (this.defaultTab)
        this.defaultTab = this.getElement(this.defaultTab);

    this.attachBehaviors();
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getElement = function(ele)
{
    if (ele && typeof ele == "string")
        return document.getElementById(ele);
    return ele;
};
```

I want to change the value of defaultTab from another function. There I have used.

```
var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1");

    alert(TabbedPanels1.defaultTab);
    TabbedPanels1.defaultTab=1;
```

The alert gives me the screen shot[image]. And the value is not changing. Can anyone help me to find the problem.

Comment: Do you mean that after you execute the assignment, the value of `TabbedPanels1.defaultTab` is not 1? How did you confirm this?

Comment: Yes, it is not assigning the value.

Comment: How did you determine that the value was unchanged? (Note that you are calling `alert` before making the assignment.)

Comment: It is for changing the selected tab in html it is not selecting the tab 1. If I assign the value from the prototype it is working but not by this.

Comment: You need to do more than change the value of `defaultTab` to actually change the tab. Note that your constructor modifies `defaultTab` after first setting its value to 0. (There may be further use of `defaultTab` when the constructor calls `attachBehaviors`.) You need to repeat that processing when you change the value; it doesn't happen all by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution

```
TabbedPanels1['defaultTab'].value
```

Here it is showing the value and I set it to 1 by this way.

```
TabbedPanels1['defaultTab'].value = 1;
```

It is working.

Comment: You should mark this answer as the solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are changing the value of a property after having executed the code to select the corresponding element.

You should do something similar to this:

```
Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels = function(element, opts)
{
    this.element = this.getElement(element);
    this.defaultTab = 0; // Show the first panel by default.
    this.tabSelectedClass = "TabbedPanelsTabSelected";
    this.tabHoverClass = "TabbedPanelsTabHover";
    this.tabFocusedClass = "TabbedPanelsTabFocused";
    this.panelVisibleClass = "TabbedPanelsContentVisible";
    this.focusElement = null;
    this.hasFocus = false;
    this.currentTabIndex = 0;
    this.enableKeyboardNavigation = true;
    this.nextPanelKeyCode = Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_RIGHT;
    this.previousPanelKeyCode = Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.KEY_LEFT;

    Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.setOptions(this, opts);

    // If the defaultTab is expressed as a number/index, convert
    // it to an element.
    this.setDefaultTab = function(tab){
        this.defaultTab = tab;
        if (typeof (this.defaultTab) == "number")
        {
            if (this.defaultTab < 0)
                this.defaultTab = 0;
            else
            {
                var count = this.getTabbedPanelCount();
                if (this.defaultTab >= count)
                    this.defaultTab = (count > 1) ? (count - 1) : 0;
            }

            this.defaultTab = this.getTabs()[this.defaultTab];
        }

        // The defaultTab property is supposed to be the tab element for the tab content
        // to show by default. The caller is allowed to pass in the element itself or the
        // element's id, so we need to convert the current value to an element if necessary.

        if (this.defaultTab)
            this.defaultTab = this.getElement(this.defaultTab);
    }
    this.setDefaultTab(this.defaultTab);
    this.attachBehaviors();
};

Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels.prototype.getElement = function(ele)
{
    if (ele && typeof ele == "string")
        return document.getElementById(ele);
    return ele;
};
```

And then you can change the tab using the function...

```
var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1");


TabbedPanels1.setDefaultTab(1);
alert(TabbedPanels1.defaultTab);
```